# What is the philosophy of words in languages?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

It has always been a question for me that when we humans did not have a language to communicate with each other and then we needed to create a language to communicate with each other, how exactly did we create words for objects and different things in general?

For example, consider a word like "water" in English. Well, we know that this word (and in general, almost all words) was not like this from the beginning. For example, maybe the root of this word is the word "wet" or another word. Anyway, how did an early human decide to choose a word like "water" for water?

Well, I know that language is just an appointment so that we can communicate with each other, but the appointment has a reason and it does not happen without a reason.

Imagine that you are a person who doesn't know any language and now you want to create a language for yourself. After defining the alphabet of your language, you now need to make words for different things. How do you do this?  How and for what reason did early humans choose a word like "God" for example for God?

Comment: Hello, Amin. This question is no longer very philosophical, but rather is studied by scientists called linguists. In fact, there's a subdiscipline called historical linguistics that is concerned with exactly these sorts of questions. I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/. A philosopher of language could speculate, but there's a lot of knowledge of words and language these days that is rooted in science.

Comment: I'd start here. [What is the consensus on how wards are formed across cultures generally?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/what-is-the-consensus-on-how-words-are-formed-across-cultures-generally).

Comment: This is really a question for linguistics. Mostly, theories on it are speculation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language

Comment: Like so many questions of the form "What is the X?" — where X stands for some kind of thing satisfying some conditions — it is not at all clear that there is such a unique thing. In which case, without uniqueness the word "the" is misleading and inappropriate.

Comment: Maybe some attempts at a **scientific** approach to the origins may help... See e.g. Daniel Everett, [How Language Began: The Story of Humanity's Greatest Invention (2017, Liveright)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/How_Language_Began_The_Story_of_Humanity/RtpDDQAAQBAJ) as well as Ronald Planer & Kim Sterelny, [From Signal to Symbol: The Evolution of Language (2021, MIT Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/From_Signal_to_Symbol/ErVCEAAAQBAJ)

Comment: I got a lot of value out of this [beginner linguistics course](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/language-families-of-the-world), which tackles this question among others. I agree with JD that this belongs on Linguistics SE.

Comment: It's thought all hominids had a raised palette, associated with vocalising. No apes do. That divergence began with two chromosomes fusing, which allowed genes within the new chromosome to move more. Only elephants, parrots, & humans, will sponteneously dance to music. I like thd theory that we began with singing out emotional states, & for group bonding (like howling wolves). It's notable that it's much easier to remember songs than strings of words, & their staying recallable after alzheimers onset suggests a different form of memory involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Traditionalist View

One of the most enduring and pervasive myths/archetypes that span the world's cultures is the idea that (a) there was — and in some mystic principle sense **is** — only one language whose origin is sacred. (b) That single unitary language due to some lapse/mistake/error/sin got divided into many.

Some select examples:

### Maidu

The Maidu is a tribe from South California
[Matthew Bronson](https://www.academia.edu/3704633/Rekindling_the_Flutes_of_Fire_Why_Indigenous_Languages_Matter_to_Humanity) tells their colorful language myth

> Mouse was blowing his flutes of fire and heating up the rocks for the people in the sweat lodge.  He would drop them though a hole in the roof and the people near the rocks would be warmed and would speak to each other, the way people should, in Maidu. Just then, Coyote came around and distracted Mouse from his duties, and he stopped. The people in the sweat lodge who were farther away from the hot rocks then grew cold. In fact, they were so cold their teeth began to chatter.  And all those people could only chatter; they never learned to speak “properly,” and that is how all the other languages of the world came to be.

### Bible

Perhaps the best known such is from the Bible, Genesis 11 [emphasis mine]

> 1 And **the whole earth was of one language, and of one speech.**
> 2 And it came to pass, as they journeyed from the east, that they found a plain in the land of Shinar; and they dwelt there.
> 3 And they said one to another, Let us make brick, and burn them thoroughly. And they had brick for stone, and slime had they for morter.
> 4 And they said, Let us build us a city and a tower, whose top may reach unto heaven; and let us make us a name, lest we be scattered abroad upon the face of the whole earth.
> 5 And the Lord came down to see the city and the tower, which the children of men builded.
> 6 And the Lord said, Behold, **the people is one**, and they have all one language; and this they begin to do: and now **nothing will be restrained from them, which they have imagined to do.**
> 7 Let us go down, and there **confound their language**, that they may not understand one another's speech.
> 8 So the Lord scattered them abroad from thence upon the face of all the earth: and they left off to build the city.
> 9 Therefore is the name of it called Babel; because the Lord did there confound the language of all the earth: and from thence did the Lord scatter them abroad upon the face of all the earth.

### Hinduism

[Panini](https://vediccafe.blogspot.com/2012/08), the original grammarian who systematized Sanskrit has this verse:

> > At the end of His Cosmic Dance, Shiva, the Lord of Dance, with a view to bless the sages Sanaka and so on, played on His [damaru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damaru) fourteen times,
> > from which emerged the following fourteen Sutras, popularly known as Shiva Sutras or Maheshvara Sutras
>
> The fourteen sounds of the Maheshwara Sutra, also known as the 'akshara-samamnaya', or the 'recitation of phonemes', is also the most ancient known Sanskrit alphabet sequence.

### Islam

Since Arabic is sacred the Koran [may not be translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran_translations)

> According to Islamic theology, the Qurʻan is a revelation very specifically in Arabic, and so it should only be recited in Quranic Arabic. Translations into other languages are necessarily the work of humans and so, according to Muslims, no longer possess the uniquely sacred character of the Arabic original. Since these translations necessarily subtly change the meaning, they are often called "interpretations"

### Judaism Hebrew

There seems to be similar mythology around Judaism and [Hebrew](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Hebrew-the-Holy-language). Also in Kabbalah, [Hebrew is the unique sacred language](https://www.bl.uk/hebrew-manuscripts/articles/the-power-of-language-in-jewish-kabbalah)

## The Relative Viewpoint

Once we've accepted the empirical fact of language multiplicity and diversity, the key ideas to explore are *linguistic relativity/determinism*, often described as Sapir-Whorf theory.

The best summary rendering I've seen of it contrasts the common sense view of language as the *cloak model* vs the view of Sapir and Whorf which is the *mold model*. The cloak model positions language as coming after the world and cloaking it with descriptions, communications. Whereas the mold model sees the world as fitting in a world view, the mold, which is determined by language.

Curiously the mold view — language creates the world — recapitulated in the gospel of John:

> In the beginning was *Logos* and *Logos* was with God and *Logos* was God. He was with God in the beginning. **Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made.**

<sup>Note 1.*Logos* is often translated as Word (capital W). But being related to logic and the various fields — "-logy", sometimes hermeneutical scholars see fit to not lose the polysemy of the word and leave it transliterated but not translated — *Logos*</sup>

<sup>Note 2. The him refers to Word. When we restore 'Word' to *Logos*, the English seems misgendered. I don't know enough Greek to speak of the original</sup>

So from God comes his Word *Logos* which is — if I may mix systems — the creative Shakti that generates the Cosmos.

## Nietzsche

As with so much else, Nietzsche offers a view that transcends tradition and secular relativism

> You say you don't believe in God, yet you believe in grammar?