# On philosophy of language?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

What are the current theories which deal with the time evolution of language? Are they retroactive or predictive?

Comment: Please state explicitly what you mean by "time evolution of language".

Comment: Well if I have a theory or metaphysical way of thinking of the time evolution of language (community consensus) then it makes sense to talk about "time evolution of language"

Comment: There is a Linguistics SE. I know nothing about it, but they might have answers for you.

Comment: You may find the cute Maidu language myth and other traditions useful [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/100705/37256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly no one knows. The initial languages emerged out of context and although historians have tried to make the links so to say, to support an evolutionary proccess, it is obvious if you look at the facts that this isn't the case. Then, most modern languages emerged out of the initial ones while people spread out by forming different civilizations.

Comment: The best researched family of languages is the language tree of Indo-European languages. For a reference see https://www.amazon.de/Indo-European-Language-Culture-Introduction-Linguistics/dp/1405188960